# Very high values in top command Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, fan, top

I am getting very high VIRT values of applications in the top command even though I just turned on my laptop. Also the laptop's fan is turning on very frequently even with just a browser and VSCode open.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and AMD Ryzen 3 5300U with Radeon graphics.

Results of `top` :

[image: top command result]

Comment: You are running something heavy in your browser. Is it a video? It is OK.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes it's a YouTube video. But just one tab is open. Is it okay to get these high values? Also, I think because of this fan is also turning on frequently. Is there a way to reduce fan toggling on and off? I am fed up with this issue.

Comment: It is normal for Ubuntu. Hardware video acceleration is disabled in most of browsers. If you are fed up, you can use another OS.

Comment: Okay got it! I thought it was something else that is generating this issue. Thank you.

Comment: You can try to find ho to enable hardware acceleration. But it is really tricky and rarely works well. Or you can watch videos not in browsers. There are players that work.

Comment: @Nmath i think you didnt found any relation b/w the 2 but i asked an actual problem. Processes are directly related to "laptop fans" as they heat the hardware and fan cools it down.